# Menu extracting

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, information-retrieval

I am interesting in extracting and structuring information about restaurant menus. What is needed is to extract the items from the menu in form `category / name / price`

For instance, we have the following [website](http://www.vub.ac.be/english/infofor/prospectivestudents/restaurant.html#menu). Here we have a drinks sections, and there a number of items. For that website I'd like to be able to extract

```
Drink / Cappuccino / € 1,50
SANDWICHES / filled sandwich, pistolet (round roll) or emperor roll / € 1,30
etc ...
```

Of course it shouldn't be limited only to this website.

The only way I can see to handle that is applying a bunch of regexps, but I don't believe listing all possible dish names is feasible.

I know that the topic might be too broad for a question, but anyway any suggestions or references to relevant articles or books will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This seems quite possible. You many not be able to list all possible dishes but **you can list all possible categories**.

Assuming that in every menu, dish names follows category name and it is followed by the price, you can identify dish names.

The algorithm will look like this:

```
foreach(category: category_list):
    foreach(word:document):    
        if(category == word):
            dish = Read next(if data is structures with table read next row or col)
            price = Read next and check it format to see if its Currency or a price
```

The point is you will need to analyse different websites to understand how the information is structured and prepare your algorithm to deal with all possible structures.